# Zabbix: Nagios like hosts/services status list

Tags: zabbix

How can I have a screen or view in Zabbix where I can see all or all problematic services/hosts in a status list like the one in Nagios?

Below a screenshot of Nagios problematic services status list for those who are not familiar with Nagios.

I have looked high and low (manual, google, forums, faqs), but could not find one. Overview is overwhelming, dashboard widgets gave only summaries, triggers are not grouped by hosts, and also overwhelming, when there's an issue.

Performance and graphing is really astonishing in Zabbix, but these status pages are killer features for me.

[image: Nagios problematic services status list]

Answer (score 3):

Zabbix has no direct analog for this page, and I for one am glad. That Nagios page really doesn't give me a good sense of priority, precisely because the alerts are grouped by host. So it's much less useful than it could be.

The best you can really do (and probably should have already done) is to define [IT Services](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/it_services). This will give you a more high-level, priority-based view into your infrastructure, as well as filtering out some noise for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Zabbix v2, there's an "Overview" item in the "Monitoring" tab.

Comment: The Nagios page that the questioner is describing shows only servers with issues. The Zabbix overview shows more than that and doesn't scale well at all if he/she has lots of servers and services.  The triggers page is probably the closest analog to what he/she is looking for.

Comment: Just as if I would have said it. 
We have more than 200 servers with about 2000 checks. Services are mostly related to a few servers. If something is wrong in Nagios I can see at once what's wrong, not just that something is wrong as in Zabbix overview or an overwhelming list of triggers. Though to find out when it became wrong I have to check Munin graphs separately, and that's where Zabbix would have a great advantage.